# CEF / CEFSharp Compiling Issue

Tags: cefsharp

```
Environment: Windows 10, WinForm (.Net 4.7.2) x64 only, CefSharp 71.0.2.0
```

We need support for playing MP4 in our product (we have a license) and we are attempting to recompile CEF with proprietary codecs enabled.

We're using the instructions from: 
https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md#markdown-header-windows-setup

Our create.bat file looks like:

```
set CEF_USE_GN=1
set GN_DEFINES=is_win_fastlink=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2015 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
call cef_create_projects.bat
```

Our update.bat file looks like

```
set CEF_USE_GN=1
set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2015 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
python ..\automate\automate-git.py --download-dir=C:\code\chromium_git --depot-tools-dir=C:\code\depot_tools --no-distrib --no-build --branch=3578
```

We are trying to specifically target build 3578 to match the build that comes with CEFSharp. We also enabled proprietary codec using the flag: proprietary_codecs=true

After about 2 hours and no errors the build completes successfully. When we run our page using cefclient.exe from the output build everything works as expected, the video plays correctly.

We copy the following files from the output build folder to our .Net application replacing the files packaged with CEFSharp:

```
cef.pak
cef_100_percent.pak
cef_200_percent.pak
cef_extensions.pak
chrome_elf.dll
d3dcompiler_47.dll
devtools_resources.pak
icudtl.dat
libcef.dll
libEGL.dll
libGLESv2.dll
natives_blob.bin
snapshot_blob.bin
v8_context_snapshot.bin
\locales\*.*
\swiftshader\libEGL.dll
\swiftshader\libGLESv2.dll
```

When running our app, the app terminates immediately and this is written to the debug.log file:

```
[0326/094610.429:FATAL:cookie_manager_impl.cc(620)] Check failed: false. context not valid
Backtrace:
cef_string_utf16_to_upper [0x00007FFD2B53E1E5+1713061]
cef_string_utf16_to_upper [0x00007FFD2B53D44D+1709581]
cef_string_utf16_to_upper [0x00007FFD2B5765D5+1943445]
cef_zip_reader_create [0x00007FFD2B3107B8+159661640]
cef_cookie_manager_get_global_manager [0x00007FFD219B0436+54]
CefCookieManager::GetGlobalManager [0x00007FFD7322879E+94]
(No symbol) [0x00007FFD4E1C07DE]

[0326/094721.035:FATAL:cookie_manager_impl.cc(620)] Check failed: false. context not valid
```

I was able to see that 71.0.2.0 uses CEF 3.3578.1870.gc974488 / Chromium 71.0.3578.98 from:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/7d24861e7af79fc4721eb498bb8417b5aa6cad97

When we run cefclient.exe from our build and navigate to chrome://about it displays:

```
CEF 3.3578.1870.gc974488
Chromium    71.0.3578.98
```

Which matches the CEFSharp release notes page.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Personally I would look at using https://github.com/mitchcapper/CefSharpDockerfiles as it has scripts for building `CEF` and `CefSharp.